# Change a custom view height based on the label height Swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios-autolayout

[image: ?]

I marked the view inside a circle, the vertical line. .I want to increase its height when the right side labels height increases. The labels become multi line based on the content.Help me figure it out. Is there have any autolayout way to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement viewDidLayoutSubviews, inside it take the height of the UILabel and modify your line height based on it.